# How to take input value of a component and render it in another component and pass back

Tags: reactjs

I have two components: `InputValues` and `AddProject`. I am using a form tag in `AddProject` and using `InputValues` component inside of `AddProject`. On click of submit button I would like to get the text box value in the `handleSubmit()` function. How can I do that?

```js
export class InputValues extends Component {
  updateText() {
    this.setState(
      {
        title: this.refs.title.value
      },
      function() {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref="title" onChange={this.updateText.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class AddProject extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { title: '' };
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    this.setState(
      {
        title: this.refs.title.value
      },
      function() {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <InputValues />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is change your `InputValues` to a "pure functional component". This is a little cleaner since you're already managing the state (title) in the parent component. We'll put a placeholder in there for allowing the parent to handle the change. Note that the value is also set from the props, which means the parent controls every aspect of the input now: it really is just a "dumb" UI element.

```
function InputValues(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={props.value} onChange={props.onInputChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then make the handler on the parent component and access the state there in your `onsubmit`. A couple of things to note: we bind `this` for `handleInputChange` in the constructor, so that we can access `this.setState`. We can get the new value via `e.target.value`. This is pretty much the same exact stuff that the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) go through. You can access `this.state.title` in the submit handler to check whatever you want to check.

```
class AddProject extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { title: '' };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState(
      {
        title: e.target.value
      },
      function() {
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    );
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // validate and do whatever is appropriate here
    if (this.state.title === "Expected Title") {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <InputValues value={this.state.title} onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```